# Meaning of the colon and x in getent group

Tags: group

I came across the command `getent group sudo` to list sudoers in sudo group and I got the output `sudo:x:27:lion` now I wounder what is the meaning of `:x:`, colon and `27` ... also I see same symbols in `/etc/passwd`... so what do these symbols mean ?

Comment: Why the downvoting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same output as this:

```
grep ^sudo: /etc/group
```

- `sudo` is the group name
- `x` represents a password field
- `27` is the GID (Group ID)
- `lion` is a member of the `sudo` group

Groups can have passwords, too; and their passwords are stored in `/etc/gshadow`.

- `man gpasswd`
- `man gshadow`

Comment: It's not *always* the same as `grep ... /etc/group` because `getent group` can fetch group info from multiple sources (including `/etc/group`, LDAP, NIS, and other sources defined in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`).  This is why it's recommended to use `getent` rather than directly extracting info from files like `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group` etc.

Answer (score 5):

[`getent group`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1.html) displays entries from the group database. The local group database is the file `/etc/group`, whose format is documented in the [`group(5)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/group.5.html).

Each line in this file is a database entry, representing one group. The columns on a line are separated by a colon. The second column is the password hash.

The user database [`/etc/passwd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html) has a similar format, with different contents in the columns. The first two columns are the name and password hash, like with the group.

These files have a column for the password only for backward compatibility. Normally the password hash is not in the publicly readable user/group database, but in another database called the [shadow database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_password) ([`/etc/shadow`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shadow.5.html) for users, [`/etc/gshadow`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/gshadow.5.html) for groups) which contains password hashes and other account information such as expiry dates, and which can only be read by privileged processes.

It's extremely rare to put a password on a group: normally some users are in the group and the other users aren't. So you can expect the `gshadow` entries to have `*` in the password hash column (this isn't a valid hash, it's a marker indicating that there is no way to gain access to the user/group by entering a password).